# Crosstab Query results in changing column names

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Using Access 2016 to create an app that keeps track of a team's availability.  Looks something like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+      
|                         << < 1/1/2018 > >>                    |
|        | 1/1/2018 | 1/2/2018 | 1/3/2018 | 1/4/2018 | 1/5/2018 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|Jake    |Available |Unavail   |Available |Unavail   |Available |
|John    |Unavail   |Available |Available |Available |Unavail   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To be able to do this I am using a Crosstab Query, which can be found below:

```
PARAMETERS DayTemp DateTime;
TRANSFORM First(Schedule.Availability) AS Availability
SELECT Schedule.UserID
FROM Schedule
WHERE (((Schedule.Day)>=[DayTemp] And (Schedule.Day)<=(DateAdd("d",7,[DayTemp]))))
GROUP BY Schedule.UserID
PIVOT Format([Day],"Short Date");
```

Which results in a query that looks Like:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|UserID |1/1/2018 | 1/2/2018 | .... | 1/5/2018|
+---------------------------------------------+
|1      |Available|..........|......|Unavail  |
|2      |Unavail  |..........|......|Available|
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The issue I'm having is that the column headings are always changing based on the date (e.g. 1/1/2018 vs 1/8/2018 vs 1/15/2018), which makes it impossible to bind controls to.  How do I go about solving this?  Maybe a better database setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're displaying dates relative to `DayTemp`, you can express your column names relative to it as well:

```
PIVOT DATEDIFF('d', [DayTemp], [Day]);
```

Which would result in:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|UserID |0        | 1        | .... | 4       |
+---------------------------------------------+
|1      |Available|..........|......|Unavail  |
|2      |Unavail  |..........|......|Available|
+---------------------------------------------+
```